# Updating ProgressBar value within a for loop

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I attempted to update a `ProgressBar` value within a for loop. Its progress should update every 100 miliseconds but unfortunately it didn't work! Here's the code:

```
pb = new ProgressBar(0);
Button btn = new Button("Start!");
btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        for(int i = 0; i <=100; i++){
            position = i;
            Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    pb.setProgress(position);
                    System.out.println("Index: "+position);
                }
            });
            try{
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }catch(Exception e){ System.err.println(e); }
        }
    }
});
```

**Question 1:** I was expecting the above code to update the progressbar every 100 miliseconds but it didn't work. Why?

**Question 2:** I called `System.out.println("Index: "+position);` within the loop. I assumed that the output should be `1..2..3..4...` but I was wrong. The output is something like this:

```
Index: 100
Index: 100
Index: 100
Index: 100
Index: 100
Index: 100
Index: 100
```

Comment: There are multiple issues with your code, the first one being running the loop on the JavaFX application thread. Since, your loop puts the current thread to sleep, I would run it on a background thread.

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: I would rather put an answer instead of writing comments, give me some time :)

Comment: Unrelated: code tags are for ... code (vs. arbitrary highlighting ;) Tagging keywords or class/method names is borderline (read: debated) - personally I rarely do it because it interrupts the reading flow (@ItachiUchiha as well, JavaFX Application thread is unrelated to actual code ;-)

Comment: @kleopatra I am sorry, I have no idea what you are talking about :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Background**

1. `Platform.runLater()` is called to execute something on the `JavaFX Application thread` when you are on some other thread. You are running it every 100ms when you are already on the JavaFX application thread adding all these items in queue, because the thread is already busy running the loop and sleeping :)

   So it runs everything in queue after the thread is free to execute them i.e. after finishing the loop.
2. There is another problem, [ProgressBar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ProgressBar.html) has a [progressproperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ProgressIndicator.html#progressProperty) whose value can be between 0 and 1, where 0 represents 0% and 1 represents 100%. If you want to update the progress bar, you would want to set the progress with values between 0.1 to 1.0.

**How to FIX**

You should start a new Thread on the button's action and let it handle the loop. You can use `Platform.runLater` inside this thread, without choking the JavaFX application thread.

I would run something as below :

```
btn.setOnAction(event -> {
    new Thread(() -> {
         for(int i = 0; i <=100; i++){
            final int position = i;
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                pb.setProgress(position/100.0);
                System.out.println("Index: " + position);
            });
            try{
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }catch(Exception e){ System.err.println(e); }
         }
    }).start();
});
```

**Note :** *This answer stresses more on where the OP went wrong and how he can rectify it. If you are on JavaFX, you would want to use better approaches i.e. using [`Task`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) and its [`updateProgress()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#updateProgress-double-double-) for updating the progress of the ProgressBar as stated by @kleopatra in her solution.*

Comment: Thank you Sir! That was genius!

Comment: _JavaFX application thread_ isn't code, is it? So why do you use the code tag ;-)

Comment: I use the coding tag to highlight phrases in my answers. Feel free to edit :)

Comment: it's obvious that you do it - but it's not meant for general highlighting ;-) Too lazy to search for the link of a debate on meta, maybe it's even discouraged in the formatting help .. but no, won't do anything about it, just need venting occasionally <g>

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to re-inventing the wheel by manually calculating and setting the progressProperty of the bar is to use a Task: it has a progressProperty that  auto-calculates the relative amount and guarantees to update on the FX-application thread, such that it is safe to bind any scene-related property to.

Something like:

```
Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {

    @Override
    protected Void call() throws Exception {
        double max = 137;
        for (int i = 0; i <= max; i++) {
            updateProgress(i, max);
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
        return null;
    }

};
button.setOnAction(e -> {
    // a task is not reusable, disable
    button.setDisable(true);
    // bind "late" to not get an initial indeterminate PB
    bar.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());
    new Thread(task).start();
});
```

Obviously, this is the very barest snippet - see [Task](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) for examples that play nicely with cancelling/interrupting the thread.